# Matplotlib: plotting discrete values

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I am trying to plot the following !

```
from numpy import *
from pylab import *
import random

for x in range(1,500):
    y = random.randint(1,25000)
    print(x,y)   
    plot(x,y)

show()
```

However, I keep getting a blank graph (?). Just to make sure that the program logic is correct I added the code `print(x,y)`, just the confirm that (x,y) pairs are being generated.

(x,y) pairs are being generated, but there is no plot, I keep getting a blank graph.

Any help ?

Comment: Arkapravo, i have no problem w/ the accepted answer; i just wanted to mention that this five-line template: from matplotlib import pyplot as PLT; fig=PLT.figure(); ax1=fig.add_subplot(111); ax1.plot(x, y); PLT.show(), is a quick way to get a working x-y plot 98% of the time. ('x', 'y' are lists or 1D Numpy arrays, btw).

Comment: @doug: you can go the same thing in a simpler way: `from matplotlib import pyplot at plt; plt.plot(x, y); plt.show()`.

Comment: @doug: Thanks ! ... I accepted Daniel G's answer since it immediately solved all my issues ! .... :) .. too bad 2 answers cannot be chosen !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, I have sometimes had better success by doing

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
```

instead of using pylab, although this shouldn't make a difference in this case.

I think your actual issue might be that points are being plotted but aren't visible. It may work better to plot all points at once by using a list:

```
xPoints = []
yPoints = []
for x in range(1,500):
    y = random.randint(1,25000)
    xPoints.append(x)
    yPoints.append(y)
pyplot.plot(xPoints, yPoints)
pyplot.show()
```

To make this even neater, you can use generator expressions:

```
xPoints = range(1,500)
yPoints = [random.randint(1,25000) for _ in range(1,500)]
pyplot.plot(xPoints, yPoints)
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: +1 for 'import pyplot'--obviously for those former Matlab users, pylab is a massive convenience, but the almost interchangeable use of these two dialects in the docs, examples, etc. made Matplotlib, brilliant as it is, much harder for me to learn.

Comment: Many thanks dudes ! I guess I had last dabbled with matplotlib, sometimes in October 2009 , certain needs came up that I had to come back to it in April 2010 .

Comment: yPoints = list(map(lambda: random.randint(1,25000), xPoints)) and no need to keep track of an extra variable.